# Reading an XML file using QXmlStreamReader

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I want to read an XML file using `QXmlStreamReader`, but I really don't know where the problem is. My function reads the content of the first tag, but then it stops.

The form of the XML file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <student>
        <firstName>mina</firstName> 
        <lastName>jina</lastName>
        <grade>13</grade>
    </student>
    <student>
        <firstName>Cina</firstName> 
        <lastName>fina</lastName>
        <grade>13</grade>
    </student>
```

The function:

```
void MainWindow::open() {
    QFile file(QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open"));
    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QXmlStreamReader xmlReader;
        xmlReader.setDevice(&file);
        QList<Student> students;
        xmlReader.readNext();
        //Reading from the file
        while (!xmlReader.isEndDocument())
        {
            if (xmlReader.isStartElement())
            {
                QString name = xmlReader.name().toString();
                if (name == "firstName" || name == "lastName" ||
                        name == "grade")
                {
                    QMessageBox::information(this,name,xmlReader.readElementText());
                }
            }else if (xmlReader.isEndElement())
            {
                xmlReader.readNext();
            }
        }
        if (xmlReader.hasError())
        {
            std::cout << "XML error: " << xmlReader.errorString().data() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was in the form of the XML document. I needed to create a root tag.

The new form of the document is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <students>
        <student>
            <firstName>mina</firstName> 
            <lastName>jina</lastName>
            <grade>13</grade>
        </student>
        <student>
            <firstName>Cina</firstName> 
            <lastName>fina</lastName>
            <grade>13</grade>
        </student>
    </students>
```