# QT android application read a file.xml on mobile

Tags: android, qt

I have a QT android application and i have a file for example: text.xml (this file i copied it into a direction on mobile phone).

Is there any way to use QT to read this file from the application. I want to parse XML from that file text.xml and display some content base on that xml file on the QT application.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Just use [`QXmlStreamReader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328756/reading-a-xml-file-using-qxmlstreamreader) a question with some working code.

Comment: i have already known how to read XML using QXmlStreamReader. My point is how my app can read that file when it on a mobile phone. How can  i go to the path of that file on mobile phone.Thanks

Comment: Uhm...it depends on the directory, I guess. Mobile filesystem is still a filesystem so Qt IO can be used to navigate it. You can also use [`QStandardPaths`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) to access common locations. See the linked documentation for details about the mapped directories.